# Fluid simulation ignoring effector, and rigid body just not working at all

Tags: modifiers, physics

I have a scene set up in which liquid is supposed to fall into a martini glass and then an “eyeball” is dropped into the glass. I was following a tutorial that you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38eiWHtw-ps&t=204s&ab_channel=5MinutesBlender). You can also download my file [here](https://we.tl/t-kkceupcZVe).

I got both simulations to work only one time, but my fluid sim was FLIP resulting in all the liquid being splashed out of the glass. I am now trying to get the simulation to work with APIC. At first, my fluid simulation was working, but falling in between the vertices of my mesh - which is pretty low poly with a surface subdivision. I tried to increase the effector surface thickness, but that doesn't work unless it's up to about .9 (then the liquid isn't properly hitting the glass). I also tried adding a subdivision modifier but it made my martini glass look a bit too thick and also still didn't work. When I applied the surface subdivision modifier to the model, the liquid did work properly but the mesh had too many faces for me to bake the physic simulation and Blender would crash every single time. I have no idea to get this to work properly while also not making blender crash. (Also is it common for Blender to cars like this? I really spec-ed out my computer hoping that I wouldn't have so many crashes.)

PLUS I'm having trouble with the eyeball (my rigid object). I can get it to interact with the glass alone correctly usually. However, after tweaking the liquid sim more and more, I somehow managed to lose the correct motion. When I can get it to work, it's been bouncing out of the glass instead of just rattling around in it. I tried increasing the friction but that hasn't worked either.

Just for reference, my computer specs are as follows:
GPU:    EVGA FTW3 GeForce RTX 3080 10GB
CPU:    AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
RAM:    Crucial Ballistix 64 GB
Mother Board:   Gigabyte X570 AORUS ELITE

Any and all help with this is so greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Is the file to download the one you're working with? Just a few things, the eyeball has no rigid body physics. The martini glass has it's normals turned inside out. Some other objects have their normals also facing in different directions (but I guess that doesn't matter since they are no effectors), the fluid object has a surface emission of 0, and the worst part your domain is messed up: it has a negative scale! Also it's much too large to simulate that small area (since you don't want liquid to splash all around). And at least: you should bake your simulation, not use Replay in the Cache.

Comment: Lol I had no idea my file was ~that~ bad. I turned the rigid body off since it wasn't working and I was trying to focus on the fluid sim. I am very much a beginner! I didn't know it was possible for normals to be inside out lol. What is the difference between baking the simulation vs replay in the cache?